# Clicking the action part of @angular/service-worker push notifications

Tags: angular5

I've been trying to redirect users to the "action" part of Web push coming from the backend (PHP).

```
    return (new WebPushMessage)
        ->title('Title')
        ->icon('icon.png')
        ->body('Body Msg')
        ->action('Open Notification', 'open_notification')
        ->data(['id' => $notification->id,'url'=>'http://somewhere']);
```

Default service workers use:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    console.log('On notification click: ', event.notification.tag);
    event.notification.close();

    // This looks to see if the current is already open and
    // focuses if it is
    event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({
       type: "window"
    }).then(function(clientList) {
       for (var i = 0; i < clientList.length; i++) {
          var client = clientList[i];
              if (client.url == '/' && 'focus' in client)
                 return client.focus();
       }
       if (clients.openWindow)
          return clients.openWindow('/');
    }));
});
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/notificationclick

Angular 5 uses

```
import {SwPush, SwUpdate} from '@angular/service-worker';
```

My question then is how to interpret this in the front end (Angular 5) using @angular/service-worker

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, I think it is not documented yet.

Comment: there is an issue tu explain how it works https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22311

Comment: @brahimfes Thanks, I've subscribed to it. Hopefully, they provide something usable soon.

Comment: @brahimfes Found a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got a response from [u-ryo](https://github.com/u-ryo) on Github

There is a workaround.
Add the codes below to ngsw-worker.js around the line 
this.scope.addEventListener('push', (event) => this.onPush(event));(Line 1775).

```
  this.scope.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Notification click Received. event', event);
    event.notification.close();
    if (clients.openWindow && event.notification.data.url) {
      event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url));
    }
  });
```

Then you can specify the URL in the "notification.data.url".

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20956#issuecomment-374133852

Comment: it works for me on desktop on chrome. isnt it suppose to work on android device as well?

Comment: @Vik The url that comes from the backend is a web url i.e. www.website.com/notifications/id. That won't work for mobile. Except you have a PWA of the site on your android device.

Comment: So no way to act on notifications for the app ?

Comment: But that works on entire notification click. How to have it associate different URL on each notification action

Comment: @Vik you'll have to specify the dynamic urls from the server.

Comment: well there is option to specify just one. i need different for different actions

Comment: @Vik have a base url from the server and dynamically append your individual intended locations from the server.

Comment: @Vik PWA is Google termed, hence Android. But iOS has made it available now. https://medium.com/@firt/progressive-web-apps-on-ios-are-here-d00430dee3a7

Comment: does this not get overridden every time you run build --prod?

Comment: @Chris No, it doesn't.

Comment: @BolajiPemipo hm unfortunately it seems that it does get overridden Everytime I build the project, all changes in ngsw-worker.js are gone...

How did you overcome this limitation?

Comment: Well, I use it in Angular 5. What version of Angular are you working on? @Chris

Comment: @BolajiPemipo I am using angular 7.
i found this nice tutorial: http://jakubcodes.pl/2018/06/13/enhancing-angular-ngsw/
and registered a second custom sw for the click part - it is working pretty well so far. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have actions, and each action with a different url, here is my fix.

```
    this.scope.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
        event.notification.close();
        var payload = event.notification.data;
        var url = payload.url;
        if (event.action && payload.actions && payload.actions.length) {
            var actions = payload.actions.filter(x => x.action == event.action);
            if (actions.length && actions[0].url) {
                url = actions[0].url;
            }
        }
        if (clients.openWindow && url) {
            event.waitUtil(clients.openWindow(url));
        }
    });
```

Comment: waitUntil has a typo