# Action button push-notification not working | Node | sw-push

Tags: node.js, push-notification, notifications, service-worker, web-push

I've created a web app using MEAN stack and integrated push message notification for certain events. But how do I add link/s in the notification so the user can click and gets redirected to site on browser

here's a specimen I send

```
const notificationPayload = JSON.stringify({
            notification: {
                title: "Hello",
                body: "World,
                icon: <icon link>,
                vibrate: [100, 50],
                data: {
                    dateOfArrival: Date.now(),
                    primaryKey: 1
                },
                actions: [{
                    action: "explore",
                    title: "Checkout",
                    icon: <icon link>,
                    click_action: "https://www.google.com",  // not working
                    url: "https://www.google.com"   // not working
                }]
            }
        });
```

Resultant is good, and checkout button is clickable... but no reaction

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Okay, firstly, `NotificationAction` object is only allowed to have 3 keys:

1. **action**
2. **title**
3. **icon**

So Naturally, `click_action` & `url` will just be ignored.

Coming to your question on how to handle actions, you need to write handlers for each action in the array based on the `NotificationAction.action` key in your service worker. A detailed guide can de found [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/notification-behaviour).

**example:**

```js
self.registration.showNotification("New mail from Alice", {
  actions: [
    {
      action: 'archive',
      title: 'Archive'
    }
  ]
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  event.notification.close();
  if (event.action === 'archive') {
    // Archive action was clicked
    archiveEmail();
  } else {
    // Main body of notification was clicked
    clients.openWindow('/inbox');
  }
}, false);
```

**References:**

1. [NotificationAction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NotificationAction)
2. [NotificationEvent.action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NotificationEvent/action)
3. [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API)
4. [Displaying a notification - Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/display-a-notification)
5. [Notification behaviour](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/notification-behaviour)

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I need to handle it via Angular. It's a little different here. I've tried this code::::

importScripts('./ngsw-config.json');

self.addEventListener('explore', event => {
    console.log("event = ", event);
});

but it doesn't work. Having problem in this specific case

Comment: This might help https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/a-new-angular-service-worker-creating-automatic-progressive-web-apps-part-2-practice-3221471269a1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972973/clicking-the-action-part-of-angular-service-worker-push-notifications

Answer (score 1):

I'll setup the precise answer, that resolved my case with ngsw-worker:

this was the notification that I was sending, with it, you can send data in the data attribute:

```
notification: {
                title: "hello world,
                body: "you have a notification",
                icon: <user dp url>,
                vibrate: [100, 50],
                data: {
                    dateOfArrival: Date.now(),
                    primaryKey: 1,
                    url: <user's profile URL>   // data to be used
                },
                actions: [{
                    action: "explore",
                    title: "Checkout",
                    icon: '... some address ... jolly-roger.png',
                },
                {
                    action: 'close',
                    title: 'Close'
                }
                ]
            }
```

Now, open ngsw-worker.js. It's usually in root folder of dist (for production ready rip), or in `node_modules\@angular\service-worker\ngsw-worker.js`

here, goto line that handles clicks on notification (:1932: in my case)

```
this.scope.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) =>
```

and you can add your code here regarding the ULR to open. example:

```
this.scope.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
                try {
                    clients.openWindow("http://localhost:3000/#/"+event.data.url);
                } catch (e) {
                    clients.openWindow("http://localhost:3000/#/");
                } 
                this.onClick(event)
            });
```

alternatively, if you are handling it within angular itself, you can use redefine the function after injecting swPush in constructor:

```
this._swPush.notificationClicks.subscribe( event => {
      console.log("event = ", event);
});
```

Rest related articles are present in Salvio's answer below.